# Python Netflix Query

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib, netflix

I am trying to get the name of TV Show (Episode/Season)/Movie from the Netflix URL. Is there a way of doing it using `requests` and `urllib`? I guess I'll need the API key and secret for that.

This is what I'm trying to do.

e.g. I have this URL for Z Nation.

```
url = "https://www.netflix.com/gb/title/80008434"
url_data = urlparse.urlparse(url)
query = urlparse.parse_qs(url_data.query)
id = query["v"][0]
```

*id* should give me *80008434*

```
netflixurl = ''
r = requests.get(netflixurl)
js = r.json()
item = js[""]
```

*item* should give me Z Nation Season 3. (Or whatever season/episode url is url)
Using the `pyflix2` API for 'NetflixAPIV2'.
How should I go about this? Please help!

**EDIT**: I use this for youtube. Is there a similar thing for netflix?

```
import lxml
from lxml import etree
import urllib
youtube = etree.HTML(urllib.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L93-7vRfxNs").read())
video_title = youtube.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title")
song = ''.join(video_title)
```

Result : Daft Punk - Aerodynamic

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, Netflix has discontinued the use of its public API and is not accepting any new developers.

You can look into [Netflix Roulette API](http://netflixroulette.net/api/), which is an unofficial API and lets you run queries on Netflix. You can use that API in conjunction with `urllib` or `requests` and get the results that you need.

Apart from that you can use general webscraping, using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and requests. But doing it this way is not recommended as it will consume immense amount of bandwidth to scrape all the directories.

Comment: Hey! Thanks. Can I use lxml as I've done for youtube previously? In the EDIT part of my question.

Comment: *"it will consume immense amount of bandwidth"* - and, perhaps more importantly, violate Netflix's TOS and get your account suspended.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do you suggest?

Comment: @Blabber not doing it at all. If Netflix wanted you using their data, they'd provide an API. Have you considered using something like https://www.themoviedb.org/ instead (I've written a simple client for it if you need a starting point: https://github.com/textbook/atmdb)? What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that depends though, if he just wants to run query to organize a few personal shows in a one off way, it might not be a big deal. But yeah, it definitely is not a good idea.

Comment: That's what I want to do. Get all the shownames for the urls.

Comment: @Blabber, what he's trying to tell you is that it might not be legal to scrape data because Netflix has "Officially" discontinued the use of the API. They could actually suspend your account for doing that. 

I was just telling you that there *is* a way to do that. Whether you should *do* that is an ethical question which you need to consider for yourself. Although, try checking for other open databases which contain tv shows as well, maybe the one jonrsharpe recommended. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an API that you can subscribe to developed by uNoGS.  The downside is that you can have a free account but have to submit your credit card details as, if you go over 100 requests a month, you will be charged.  Needless to say alarm bells rang.
Therefore, I'm looking into building my own and in the very early stages.
Having seen some of the replies I just thought I'd throw it out there that the robots.txt file shows that the /browse subdirectory shows as 'allowed'.
Normally on websites such as this, they stipulate that they allow it for reputable search engines to be able to scrape.  There is however no such clause and therefore, with the legality, as discussed so far, it appears that scraping the browse section is both legal and ethical.  That being said, even there is no 'Crawl-delay' stipulated, ethically I would suggest putting one if you do succeed in getting a requests working.

Answer (score 0):

so I wrote some code for this exact thing as a lot of websites gave for the USA or other regions and couldn't translate to the exact answer that worked for my Netflix. 
This one uses selenium but it shouldn't be hard to downloads and understand the code that I wrote. 
https://github.com/Eglis05/netflix-selenium 
You can have a look at it and report anything you don't like. :)

Comment: Please post the physical code instead of a link.